# How can this number be converted into bit in c++?

Tags: c++, bit

I wish to convert numbers like 0x030C30C3 and 0x09249249 into bit. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "bit". Do you mean *binary*?

Comment: What does "convert number into bit" mean?

Comment: you mean binary? just use any hex to binary wiki page and convert that algorithm to c++

Comment: Each hex digit represents a group of 4 bits.
1 = 0001...
2 = 0010...
F = 1111...

The chart near the top of this page has the full set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: The problem is that a bit is either 1 or zero.  Numbers like yours will require many bits to represent.  They are too large to fit into a bit.

Answer (score 5):

The binary representation can easily be accessed and manipulated through [**`std::bitset`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
std::bitset<32> var(0x030C30C3);

std::cout << var; // binary representation
```

Comment: how to convert the thus obtained binary bits back into a double decimal number? Is it possible to convert the original double decimal into fraction this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a simple algorithm which shows how to do "conversion" then here is one:

```
#include <iostream>

void num2bin(uint32_t num)
{
    uint32_t mask = 1 << 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (num & mask)
            std::cout << 1;
        else
            std::cout << 0;
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t num = 0x030C30C3;

    num2bin(num);
}
```